# Python multiprocessing imap_unordered: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered` in Python 3.9.7 and it keeps throwing a `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. I have searched around and cannot figure this out. It seems to be coming from deep in the multiprocessing library.

To make matters more confusing, I have ran this same code hundreds of times. It runs without errors most of the time, but throws this error randomly.

Here is how I am calling it.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
for result in pool.imap_unordered(method, getIterations(), chunksize=256):
    [process result]
```

Originally, I had `getIterations()` as a generator. I thought maybe this was the issue, so I switched it to build and return a full list and am still seeing the error.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyPythonFile.py", line 555, in <module>
    Simulator().run()
  File "MyPythonFile.py", line 323, in run
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(method, getIterations(), chunksize=256):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 448, in <genexpr>
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 870, in next
    raise value
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I have also tried changing chunk size. If I go low enough (64 or less), it doesn't seem to happen as often, but then everything takes much longer.

***Edit***
After further examination, I believe imap_unordered might just be hiding the original cause of error - which I now believe is coming from the `[process result]` code I did not include in the original question.

Here more of the code, so maybe the question is: why is the `Lock` not working?

I didn't even think I should need a `Lock` here, but I tried. I thought the `for` loop would serialize the results so this dictionary wouldn't be accessed concurrently anyway.

```
resultByKey = {}
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
for fullResult in pool.imap_unordered(method, getIterations(), chunksize=256):
    (key, result) = fullResult

    lock.acquire()

    if key not in resultByKey:
        resultByKey[key] = []
    resultByKey[key].append(result)

    lock.release()
```

***Edit 2 Workaround***
I changed my code to the following and it seems to be working (can't be 100% sure since this doesn't occur every attempt). I don't love having to build an unnecessary list in this solution, but it is an acceptable workaround if it runs consistently.

I would still like to understand why this works and the original code doesn't.

```
fullResultList = []
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for fullResult in pool.imap_unordered(method, getIterations(), chunksize=256): 
        fullResultList.append(fullResult)

resultByKey = {}
for fullResult in fullResultList:
    (key, result) = fullResult
    if key not in resultByKey:
        resultByKey[key] = []
    resultByKey[key].append(result)
```

Comment: Either method may not be stable or the implementation of imap_unordered. Is this error also occurring with `pool.imap`?

Comment: Haven't tied ```pool.imap```, I will switch to that, run a few tests and get back to you. Thanks for the input.

Comment: ```pool.imap``` throws the same error. After further examination, I think the dictionary size change might actually be in the original ```[process result]``` code that I left out. Still not sure why, but edited the question.

Comment: It's definitely an error in your function `method`.  You can check by seeing this line  `File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 870, in next
    raise value` . Over here, in `pool.py` code, `value` is only raised if the task was unsuccessful. What's strange though is that a `RemoteTraceback` should have been added on as well, which detailed where exactly your code went wrong. Can you confirm this is the full traceback? Try to see if you can post a reproducible sample.

Comment: That is the full stack trace I got. I don't think it is a problem with ```method``` only because if I comment out the ```[process result]``` part and instead just print a message, this error never occurs.

Comment: Added a workaround to the question. I still do not understand why the original code doesn't work and this does.

Comment: Can you show a sample return value of `method`. This problem is likely to be implementation specific.

Comment: ```(key, result)``` is basically the return value of ```method```. The only difference is in my code, there are multiple keys in the tuple (e.g., ```(keyA, keyB, keyC, ..., result)```) and there is a different dictionary modified per ```key``` (e.g., ```resultByKeyA```, ```resultByKeyB```, etc.). However, it is the code I showed above replicated for each ```key```/```dict``` combo.

Comment: The original code is not working because changes to the shared dictionary are not synchronised between the processes. You could use a `Manager` to ensure that.

Comment: Do I misunderstand how this works? I thought the only thing executed in multiple processes would be the items in the ```method``` passed to the ```imap_unordered```. I thought the shared dictionaries in the ```for``` loop would be executed in serial by the main process. If I am wrong, I will dive deeper into the documentation.